# Posting a form via AJAX in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to do an Ajax post with JQuery in IE11. I have modified to compatibility meta-tag for ie-9 but it still does not work, will not send the post. Instead it throws an error saying `{exception}    Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference` from jquery.

head

```
<head id="Head1">
<link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/.../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../Scripts/UtilityFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/.../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1;IE=9;IE=8;IE=7" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Content/images/favicon.ico" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" /></head>
```

jquery

```
$('#EmailForm').validate({
            invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {
                    var message = errors == 1
                      ? '1 email field has a missing or invalid email address. It has been highlighted, please correct this or remove the field.'
                      : errors + ' email fields have  missing or invalid email addresses. It has been highlighted, please correct this or remove the fields.';
                    $("div.error span").html(message);
                    $("div.error").show();
                } else {
                    $("div.error").hide();
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit(function () {
                    history.go(-1);
                });
            }
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.remove_field', function () {
            $(this).closest('p').remove();
        });
        $('.add_email_button').closest('p').click(function () {
            var html = '<p><input type="email" class="email" form="EmailForm" required name="EmailAddresses" /><span class="btn_orange"><a href="#" class="remove_field">x</a></span></p>';
            $(html).insertBefore($(this));
        });
        $('#SendEmail_Button').closest('span').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#EmailForm').submit();
           @* if ($('#EmailForm').valid()) {
                $.post('@Url.Action("PostEmail")', $('#EmailForm').serialize()).done(function() {
                    history.go(-1);
                });
            }*@
        });
```

web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear/>
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=IE9"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
$("#EmailForm").validate({
    // options
});
```

before you can use `$("#EmailForm").valid()`.

For the history movement, do it after the AJAX completes:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit(function() {
        history.go(-1);
    });
}
```

Comment: I've update my question above  with your suggestion but this still does not work. This even breaks it in chrome. In chrome it will go back in history but the POST is not working

Comment: Going back in history reloads the page. All scripts stop when you do that.

Comment: Thats why I put it last

Comment: It doesn't matter. AJAX is asynchronous. When the script stops, it doesn't send the submission.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem in Chrome, is there a work around  in IE?

Comment: The right thing to do is put `history.go()` in the AJAX callback function.

Comment: ` $.post('@Url.Action("PostEmail")', form.serialize()).done(function() {
                    history.go(-1);
                });` ?

Comment: Thanks, the submit handler still doesn't work when I call $('#EmailForm').submit();  I'll update the onclick for SendEmail_Button above